# Regex to validate if a string has 2 consecutive letters(not 2 consecutive alphabet)

Tags: java

Conditions :

1. Contains only alphabet, hyphens and apostrophes.
2. Contains at least 2 consecutive letters
3. Does not start or end with space or hyphen
4. Contains minimum length of 2.

Valid: `a-gm-k,ak,h-'kj,um'h-k`
Invalid: `a-h-j,`

Tried `^([a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z'-]*[a-zA-Z'])$`
This is filing for the consecutive condition
Wrote  `\\b([a-zA-Z])\\1+\\b` but this is failing if I give `aa`

Can somebody please advise how to write a single regex expression for above conditions?

Comment: Why (3) fail on heading/trailing _space_ if (1) only contains alphabet, hyphens, apostrophes ?

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of positive lookaheads `(?=)` needs to be applied:

```
(?=([-'A-Za-z]{2,}))(?=^[^- ].*[^- ]$)(?=.*[A-Za-z]{2,}.*)
```

where:

- `(?=([-'A-Za-z]{2,}))` - contains only hyphen, apostrophe, or letters, minimum length of 2
- `(?=^[^- ].*[^- ]$)` - does not start or end with `-` or space
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z]{2,}.*)` - contains at least two consecutive letters

[Online demo: Regexplanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydvkwgkr)
[Online demo: regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J7PfZ4/1)

Comment: @hc_dev, updated the link, thanks for letting know.

Comment: Great, they work using _Matcher_'s `find()`. See [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/7jPp9U)